# Home plant identification and care

Tags: identification, plant-care

I recently recieved this plant (see image below) from my family, but they ripped out the identification ticket and they couldn't tell what kind of it is.

To give it the best care I can, I figured asking you, as this platform has helped me a couple of times in the past.

Right now, I got it hanging from the ceiling, with indirect sun light. It's in a pot (the one it's bought in) inside the hanging pot.

If possible, I'd love to know what plant I'm dealing with and how much water / what care it needs.

Thanks!

[image: Plant identification]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer says, it is the "spider plant", Chlorophytum comosum.

A hanging pot is a good place, because it flowers on the end of long stalks and which will hang down. and then produce "baby" plants.

It stores water in its roots, so it can survive long dry spells. In fact they can re-grow from the roots even if the plant looks completely "dead" and with no surviving leaves.

Don't over-water it, or the roots may start to rot. Over-watering is probably the only way you can kill them. A really good soaking once every one or two weeks is better than keeping the compost constantly wet by watering "little and often."

Answer (score 0):

Its Chlorophytum comosum, Spider plant. It's hardy with regard to hot temperatures, but may be best if you dont let it into the ground - it can become weedy.

Comment: That depends what you call "hardy" in your climate. They don't like temperatures below 10C / 50F, and they certainly won't survive any frost if they are grown outside.